MaxScript: How to get bitmaptexture coordinates property from UVTransform matrix?
From a bitmaptexture, you can get the uv transform values ​​from the .coords.UVTransform property in a matrix like this:
(matrix3 [1.96962,0.173648,0] [-0.347296,0.984808,0] [0,0,1] [0.268068,-0.282018,0])

Is there any way to get back the values ​​of the texture coordinate properties "Offset", "Tiling" and "Angle" from the matrix data obtained in the .coords.UVTransform property? I don't have the original texturemap, but I do have the data from the .coords.UVTransform property from original texturemap. Now I need to create a texture map by applying the data from this matrix to it.
After some experimentation, I was able to get the values ​​for the "Angle" and "Tiling" properties by taking them this way:
mySourceUVTransformMatrix=(matrix3 [1.96962,0.173648,0] [-0.347296,0.984808,0] [0,0,1] [0.268068,-0.282018,0])

myBitmapTex=Bitmaptexture()

--Tiling
myBitmapTex.coords.U_Tiling = mySourceUVTransformMatrix.scalepart[1]
myBitmapTex.coords.V_Tiling = mySourceUVTransformMatrix.scalepart[2]

-- Angle
bitmapAngle=mySourceUVTransformMatrix.rotationpart as eulerangles
myBitmapTex.coords.U_Angle = bitmapAngle.x
myBitmapTex.coords.V_Angle = bitmapAngle.y
myBitmapTex.coords.W_Angle = bitmapAngle.z

But I don't know how to get from this matrix the values ​​for the "Offset" property:
-- Offset
myBitmapTex.coords.U_Offset = ?
myBitmapTex.coords.V_Offset = ?

I understand that the "Offset" property values ​​are most likely in (matrix).row4, but when I enter these values ​​into the .coords.U_Offset=.row4[1] and .coords.V_Offset=.row4[2] properties, the bitmaptexture looks completely different.
UPD: I found the answer how to get these values ​​in 3ds Max C++ API here:
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/3ds-max-programming/how-to-get-u-offset-v-offset-from-uvtransform-matrix-of-texmap/m-p/9178908/highlight/false#M24944
auto coords = map.GetTheUVGen();
if (coords && coords->IsStdUVGen()) {
    auto const stdUVCoords = static_cast<StdUVGen*>(coords);
    /* do something with stdUVCoords->GetUOffs(time) */
}

But I need to get them via maxscript. Is there a way to compile this code in maxscript and get the values ​​for U_Offset and V_Offset?
